# How to embed the actual <esc> character in a text file

Tags: c#, text, escaping, character

I am trying to create a label with a large font on the Dymo LabelWriter 450 from a web application. I can send it a text file (we are using PrintNode for our print service) but I need to embed the actual escape character itself in the file to generate an `<esc>U` so it will use a big font. I can't figure out how to embed the actual binary `<esc>` character into a text file in my C# program. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I've tried different versions/combinations of using the `\` character but I can't figure out how to generate the binary `<esc>` character.

Comment: You can try `char ch = ((char)0x00000048);`. Also you can check the Unicode reference from [here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/)

Comment: What encoding does Dymo LabelWriter 450 require? What is the "binary `<esc>` character" (as everything is binary in the computer)?

Comment: Thanks OnePage.  You were close--the value is 0x0000001B and using your line of code and writing that value to the text file (using BinaryWriter) solved the problem.  I appreciate the help!